# Changing Button's content to DataTemplate based on ViewModel property

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, wpf-style

I have a button that I want to change its content from simple text to a DataTemplate when a bool property I have in my ViewModel is set to true. For example, the button already has a style and looks like:

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
    Content="Export"
    Style="{StaticResource NeutralButtonStyle}" />
```

Now, when a property in my viewmodel called `IsExporting` is set to `True`, I want to change the button's content from text to a specified `DataTemplate` called `LoadingSpinner`.

In a different control, I was able to achieve this in its ContentPresenter's Style triggers like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExporting}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LoadingSpinner}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

I've tried a few combinations of the above on the Button but cannot get the text to change to the DataTemplate.

The full style currently looks like:

```
<Style x:Key="NeutralButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,8" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Border
                        x:Name="BackgroundBorder"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="4">
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Update:
I'm no longer setting the initial content (a string) on the button itself.

```
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Style="{StaticResource NeutralButtonStyle}" />
```

I added these style triggers in the style above:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExporting}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource LoadingSpinner}" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExporting}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Export" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

The "False" datatrigger works. I see "Export" on the button. The DataTemplate `LoadingSpinner` does not though.

Comment: The DataTrigger could set the Button's Content instead of the ContentTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens I tried this in the style but it did not work:
`<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExporting}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource LoadingSpinner}" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>`

Comment: Your LoadingSpinner resource would then have to be the root element from the original DataTemplate, not the DataTemplate. And the initial Content must also be set by a Style Setter, not directly on the Button.

Comment: @Clemens Ahh thank you! Putting the loading spinner itself instead of the data template key worked. What is the reason for that? Also if you want to make your comment as an answer I'll mark it as answer.